# HashMap saving with ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream, bukkit

To save teleportation points on command, I have an `HashMap`:

```
public HashMap<Player, Location> mapHomes = new HashMap<>();
```

Which is accessed like this:

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sethome")){
    Location loc = player.getLocation();
    mapHomes.put(player, loc);
    sender.sendMessage("Home set !");
    return true;
}
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("home")){
    Location loc1 = mapHomes.get(player);
    player.teleport(loc1);
    sender.sendMessage("Teleported to home");
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Since these settings should be kept on restart, I've implemented a save method:

```
public void save(HashMap<Player,Location> mapHome, String path) throws NotSerializableException{
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        oos.writeObject(mapHome);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it's not working. It throws `NotSerializableException`.

I think the main problem is `Player` and `Location` are not serializable types, so what should I do to write this `HashMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` is already `Serializable`.

The problem is that the objects inside the map are not, so you'll have to make them serializable, too.

```
public class SerializedPlayer extends Player implements Serializable {
    public SerializedPlayer() {}
    public SerializedPlayer(Player playerToClone) {
        this.setField1(playerToClone.getField1());
        // Set all the fields
    }
}
```

When adding to the map:

```
map.put(new SerializedPlayer(player), new SerializedLocation(location));
```

Answer (score 1):

`NotSerializableException` is thrown when an instance is required to have a `Serializable` interface.

```
class YourClass implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Player implements Serializable {}

class Location implements Serializable {}
```

Remember, you can only serialize objects that implement the `Serializable` interface.
So your `Player` and `Location` class have to implement the interface, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing `HashMap<Player, Location>` to file.

What you need to do is make your `Player` and `Location` classes serializable.

```
public class Player implements java.io.Serializable {
    // ...
}

public class Location implements java.io.Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is already serializable.

Answer (score 0):

To make `Location` serializable, I recommend using [this class](http://pastie.org/4653888).
I wrote it myself, and just request you give me credit in the code.

```
package com.github.JamesNorris.Class;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.World;

/**
 * The class that allows location to be serialized, and be used
 * in a file. This class should not be changed, otherwise it
 * will not work for older files.
 * 
 * @author Jnorr44
 */

public final class SerializableLocation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8650311534439769069L;

    private final String world;
    private final String uuid;
    private final double x, y, z;
    private final float yaw, pitch;
    private transient Location loc;

    /**
     * Creates a new SerializableLocation instance of any org.bukkit.Location.
     * 
     * @param l
     */

    public SerializableLocation(Location l) {
        this.world = l.getWorld().getName();
        this.uuid = l.getWorld().getUID().toString();
        this.x = l.getX();
        this.y = l.getY();
        this.z = l.getZ();
        this.yaw = l.getYaw();
        this.pitch = l.getPitch();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the org.bukkit.Location back from any SerializableLocation.
     * 
     * @param l
     * @return
     */

    public static Location returnLocation(SerializableLocation l) {
        float pitch = l.pitch;
        float yaw = l.yaw;
        double x = l.x;
        double y = l.y;
        double z = l.z;
        World world = Bukkit.getWorld(l.world);
        Location location = new Location(world, x, y, z, yaw, pitch);
        return location;
    }

    // FROM HERE ON NEEDS DOC NOTES

    public SerializableLocation(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.world = (String) map.get("world");
        this.uuid = (String) map.get("uuid");
        this.x = (Double) map.get("x");
        this.y = (Double) map.get("y");
        this.z = (Double) map.get("z");
        this.yaw = ((Float) map.get("yaw")).floatValue();
        this.pitch = ((Float) map.get("pitch")).floatValue();
    }

    public final Map<String, Object> serialize() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("world", this.world);
        map.put("uuid", this.uuid);
        map.put("x", this.x);
        map.put("y", this.y);
        map.put("z", this.z);
        map.put("yaw", this.yaw);
        map.put("pitch", this.pitch);
        return map;
    }

    public final Location getLocation(Server server) {
        if (loc == null) {
            World world = server.getWorld(this.uuid);
            if (world == null) {
                world = server.getWorld(this.world);
            }
            loc = new Location(world, x, y, z, yaw, pitch);
        }
        return loc;
    }
}
```

Now simply do:

```
SerializableLocation loc = new SerializableLocation(LOCATION);
```

The reason this is required is because `Location` contains `world`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `yaw` and `pitch`, where `world` is not serializable.

Answer (score -2):

In fact, you are trying to serialize `Player` and `Location`, trying to implement new classes etc. But why are you doing this?

It would be better if you store not `Player` and `Location` objects, but their String representations instead. For example, you could use `Player.getName()` and something like `"world:100:65:100"`for location (so we can *easily* get all data back by `String.split(":")`. I think this a better approach.