# Can't read HashMap from file after updates

Tags: android, android-file

Not sure if this is the culprit, but I cant read the HashMap from file anymore (seemed to work yesterday). Here is the code to save the HashMap to file:

```
try {
    File file = new File(getDir("data_directory", MODE_PRIVATE), "map_file");
    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    outputStream.writeObject(shopKeysAndNames);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    Log.i(TAG, "written file length: " + file.length());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is the code to read the HashMap from file:

```
try {
    File file = new File(getDir("data_directory", MODE_PRIVATE), "map_file");

    Log.i(TAG, "file length: " + file.length());

    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    HashMap <String, String> newMap = (HashMap <String, String> ) inputStream.readObject();

    inputStream.close();

    Log.i(TAG, "Contents of the array: " + newMap.toString());

} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Read HashMap is always empty. Also file sizes after writing and before reading are the same. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - found the culprit, have written empty `HashMap` :(
Thanks for pointing my attention to it. This was the code to create HashMap for storage, where I have accidentally deleted line to put values to the HashMap:

```
// Temporary hashmap to store keys and names of all goods
HashMap < String, String > shopKeysAndNames = new HashMap < > ();

// Put all goods to iterable
Iterable < DataSnapshot > iterable = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

// Iterate each good and store values to hashmap
for (DataSnapshot currentGood: iterable) {

 // Good key and name
 String goodKey = currentGood.getKey();
 String goodName = (String) currentGood.child("Name").getValue();

}
```

Comment: Are your objects in hashmap `Serializable`? Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897593/hashmap-saving-with-objectoutputstream ?

Comment: My objects in hashmap are `String` and they are serializable according to this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Ah, didn't notice it.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was misleading. The `HashMap` class is serializable (apart from the `transient` discourse), so it can be written with an ObjectOutputStream (tested it and prefectly working). Are you sure you are writing `String`s? Or maybe your keys/values are instances of a custom class?

Comment: "Are you sure you are writing Strings?" This has helped me to find the stupid issue!